# jekyll-theme-primer bootsrap.min cannot be found

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

I am trying to run https://github.com/fossasia/gci18.fossasia.org/ locally.

I did it once with jekyll (on an older version of the site) and it worked.

Now, I cloned it so it is updated, but I cannot get it to work. I keep getting an error message that says

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'css/style.scss':
                File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.min. Load path: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.5.3/_sass on line 1
jekyll 3.7.4 | Error:  File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.min.
Load path: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.5.3/_sass on line 1
```

I have tried reinstalling jekyll-theme-primer but it is not working. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Your clone](https://github.com/ngmhprogramming/gci18.fossasia.org/commit/8548e51e6ffd84bd02d9ddc5ddf59a78e3b4eb12) works perfectly well.

Answer (score 0):

Per the Jekyll Documentation, you'll want to put all of your SCSS partials (such as `bootstrap.min.css`, `themify-icon.css`, and the other files imported in `/css/style.scss`) into the `/_sass/` directory for automatic conversion.

Alternatively, you can specify `.css` in your import statements. For example:

```
# /css/style.scss
@import 'bootstrap.min.css';
@import 'themify-icon.css';
...
```

See https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/#sassscss for more information.